# Loop columns of matrix with nested apply

Tags: r, loops, apply

I am trying to loop over the columns of a matrix and change certain predefined sequences within the colomns, which are available in form of vectors.

Let's say I have the following matrix:

```
m2 <- matrix(sample(1:36),9,4)

       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   11    6    1   14
[2,]   22   16   27    3
[3,]   34   10   23   32
[4,]   21   19   31   35
[5,]   17    9    2    4
[6,]   28   18   29    5
[7,]   20   30   13   36
[8,]   26   33   24   15
[9,]    8   12   25    7
```

As an example my vector of sequence starts is a and my vector of sequence ends is b. Thus the first sequence to delete in all columns is `a[1]` to `b[1]`, the 2nd `a[2]` to `b[2]` and so on.

My testing code is as follows:

```
testing <- function(x){
  apply(x,2, function(y){  
    a <- c(1,5)
    b <- c(2,8)
    mapply(function(y){
    y[a:b] <- NA; y
    },a,b)
  })
}
```

Expected outcome:

```
        [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[2,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[3,]   34   10   23   32
[4,]   21   19   31   35
[5,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[6,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[7,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[8,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[9,]    8   12   25    7
```

Actual result:

```
 Error in (function (y)  : unused argument (dots[[2]][[1]])
```

What is wrong in the above code? I know I could just set the rows to NA, but I am trying to get the above output by using nested `apply` functions to learn more about them.

Comment: In the `mapply`, you have two input i.e. a, b, but you have only one in the `function(y)`

Comment: @akrun ok if I simply add the inputs `a, b` to `function(y)` I get another error. Do you know how to fix the problem?

Comment: I still didn't understand how you got the expected output.

Comment: @akrun I cannot get the expected outcome with the above code. Of course you could easily set row 1 and 2 to NA etc or use a nested for loop, but I cannot get it done with a nested apply function.

Comment: I think `m2[unlist(Map(":", a, b)),] <- NA` is what you wanted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We get the sequence of corresponding elements of 'a', 'b' using `Map`, `unlist` to create a `vector` and assign the rows of 'm2' to NA based on that.

```
m2[unlist(Map(":", a, b)),] <- NA
m2
#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
# [2,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
# [3,]   34   10   23   32
# [4,]   21   19   31   35
# [5,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
# [6,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
# [7,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
# [8,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
# [9,]    8   12   25    7
```

Comment: The condition of your first solution cannot be applied to a more complex case. Sorry my simple example did not reflect this, but the actual start and end sequences are not of the same distance. As an example:
`a <- c(2,7,11)` and `b <- c(4,9,15)`. 

I will make a new example to better reflect this.

Comment: @EDC Thanks, I was only looking at the expected output.